# MQTT: detect if submission is completed

Tags: android, mqtt

I have a problem with the following scenario:

I Send a document from the Server to a mobile Device. I also send a notification about a new document in the inbox at the same time.

**Problem is:** Depending on the Device's Connection speed, that submission can take a while, so the notification comes in before the document is in the app's inbox.
So I want to send the Notification after the submission is completed.

**Question:** Is there a way for me to check if the MQTT data transfer is completed without having to have the client send a confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

With MQTT, it is not possible for a publisher to know that all subscribers have received the message unless the subscribers also publish an acknowledgement back on another topic.